# Get data from HTML page to Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have four user input text fields in html created to user input data. I want to pass this four values into Google spreadsheet. This HTML is created using Google Apps Script.
I am not familiar with Google Apps Script but looking badly to develop a tool. Can anyone help me to work on this

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple HTML file communicating with Google Apps Script contained in a Spreadsheet.  The HTML file and the Google Apps Script communicate with each other and I pass one array from the HTML file to the Google Script.

The Code.gs file:

```
function doGet()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
  
}

function getData(a)
{
  var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "M/d/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
  a.splice(0,0,ts);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEETID')
  ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').appendRow(a);
  return true;
}

function getURL()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEETID');
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('imgURLs');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var urlA=[];
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    urlA.push(rngA[i][0]);
  }
  return urlA;
}
```

The index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="data">
    <br />Text 1<input name="t1" type="text" size="15" id="txt1" placeholder="Text 1" />
    <br />Text 2<input name="t2" type="text" size="15" id="txt2" placeholder="Text 2" />
    <br />Text 3<input name="t3" type="text" size="15" id="txt3" placeholder="Text 3" />
    <br />Text 4<input name="t4" type="text" size="15" id="txt4" placeholder="Text 4" />
    <br /><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Member" checked />Member
    <br /><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Guest" />Guest
    <br /><input type="radio" name="Type" value="Intruder" />Intruder
    <br /><input type="button" value="submit" id="btn1" />
    <br /><img id="img1" src="" alt="img1" width="300" />
  </div>
  <div id="resp" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Response</h1>
    <p>Your data has been received.</p>
  </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#btn1').click(validate);
        $('#txt4').val('');
        $('#txt3').val('');
        $('#txt2').val('');
        $('#txt1').val('')
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(setURL)
          .getURL();
      });
      function setURL(url)
      {
        $('#img1').attr('src',url[0]);
      }
      function setResponse(a)
      {
        if(a)
        {
          $('#data').css('display','none');
          $('#resp').css('display','block');
        }
      }
      
      function validate()
      {
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1').value || '';
        var txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2').value || '';
        var txt3 = document.getElementById('txt3').value || '';
        var txt4 = document.getElementById('txt4').value || '';
        var type = $('input[name="Type"]:checked').val();
        var a = [txt1,txt2,txt3,txt4,type];
        if(txt1 && txt2 && txt3 && txt4)
        {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(setResponse)
            .getData(a);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
          alert('All fields must be completed.');
        }
      }
      
      function loadTxt(from,to)
      {
          document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }
      
      function radioValue()
      {
        var radios = document.getElementsByName('genderS');
        for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) 
        {
          if(radios[i].checked) 
          {
            return radios[i].value;
          }
        }
      }
      
      
     console.log('My Code');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```