# How to take a user input from text box and import into a google code.gs file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make an easy pop HTML editable automatic email script for emailing students and parents about missing assignments.  First problem I am running into is getting the email subject title from the HTML popup I have created.

I've already tried different forms. and get.  lines.  It doesn't seem to grab anything and the code always crashes at my log before the line:

```
var subject = form.subject;  // Title of Email with class name
```

or

```
var subject = index.html().getEmailSubject();
```

**code.gs**

```
// Send Email Script for Edit Email Section Popup HTML (using check boxes, etc.)

 function sendEmail() {

   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
   var result = ui.alert(
     'Send Emails',
     'Are you sure you want to send missing assignment emails?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

   // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Missing Student Information");
    Logger.log("test 1");
    var email_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template");
    Logger.log("test 2");
    var email_data = email_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    Logger.log("test 3");

  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();   // Number of rows to process
    Logger.log(numRows);
   // Fetch the range of cells A2:(numRows)3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6);

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows;i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var student_name = row[0];     // Gets student name
    var class = row[1];            // Gets class name
    var student_email = row[2];    // Gets student email address
    var parent_email = row[3];     // Gets parent email address
    var missing = row[4];          // Gets number of missing assignments
    var assign_list = row[5];

    Logger.log("Before get email subject header.");

    var subject = index.html().getEmailSubject();  // Title of Email with class name 
    Logger.log("starting "+student_name+" "+missing+assign_list); 

    Logger.log("After get email subject header.");
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      // Prevent forms from submitting.
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).SendEmails(formObject);
        google.script.host.close();
      }
      function updateUrl(url) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
      }
      function setDefaultSubject(subject) {
        if (subject != null && subject != "") {
          var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
          form.Subject.value = subject;
        }
      }
      function setDefaultBody(body) {
        if (body != null && body != "") {
          var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
          form.Body.value = body;
        }
      }
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(setDefaultBody)
        .getEmailBody();
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(setDefaultSubject)
        .getEmailSubject();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="checkbox" name="send_Students" checked="checked" /> Email Students <input type="checkbox" name="send_Parents" checked="checked" /> Email Parents <br/><br/>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      Email Subject: <input style="width:500px" name="Subject" type="text" value="Current Missing Assignments List"/>
      <br/name="Subject" type="text" value="Current Missing Assignments List"/>
      <br/>
      Email Body: <br/>
      <textarea name="Body" style="width:750px; height:400px">
```

I want it to just take the form from Index.html and make this the Email Subject line.

The rest of the information I am going to try to insert into the text from the google sheet everything is pulling from.

Comment: Take look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48775218/7215091

Answer (score 0):

The contents of index.html appear to be more complicated than necessary. You say that you only want the Email Subject line, so I removed index.html and adapted the ui interface to request the email line.

Also the "subject" variable was declared inside your loop which means it is called multiple times. That was unnecessary and I've moved it to a line before the loop.

---

```
// Send Email Script for Edit Email Section Popup HTML (using check boxes, etc.)

 function so5714849501() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
  var result = ui.alert(
  'Send Emails',
  'Are you sure you want to send missing assignment emails?',
  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Missing Student Information");
    //Logger.log("test 1");
    var email_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Template");
    //Logger.log("test 2");
    var email_data = email_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    //Logger.log("test 3");

    var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();   // Number of rows to process
    //Logger.log(numRows);

    // get subject line from prompt function
    var subject = showEmailPrompt();
    if (subject == undefined){
      Logger.log("DEBUG: No subject received; stopping the process.");   
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      Logger.log("DEBUG: the subject from the prompt is "+subject);    
    }

    // Fetch the range of cells A2:(numRows)3
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6);

    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows;i++) {
      var row = data[i];
      var student_name = row[0];     // Gets student name
      var class = row[1];            // Gets class name
      var student_email = row[2];    // Gets student email address
      var parent_email = row[3];     // Gets parent email address
      var missing = row[4];          // Gets number of missing assignments
      var assign_list = row[5];
      Logger.log("DEBUG: name:"+student_name+", class:"+class+", student email: "+student_email+", parent  email: "+parent_email+", number missing:"+missing+", assignments:"+assign_list);
    }
  }
 }

 function showEmailPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'Missing Assignments Email',
      'Please enter a subject or Cancel:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
    ui.alert('The Email subject will be ' + text + '.');
    return text;
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('You cancelled the process.');
    return;
  } else if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
    return;
  }
}
```