# Gathering input from HTML, then return back to HTML

Tags: google-apps-script

I don't know how to use the withSuccessHandler to return back to HTML. So I know withSuccessHandler calls to a function, but how can I pass variables with withSuccessHandler, and then return a result?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48775218/7215091) has some examples that do that:

Answer (score 0):

As you can [see](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers) in the documentation:

**CODE.GS**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getUnreadEmails() {
  return GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount();
}
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function onSuccess(numUnread) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        div.innerHTML = 'You have ' + numUnread
            + ' unread messages in your Gmail inbox.';
      }

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .getUnreadEmails();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the function ends, the `return` sends the value back to the html.

Comment: Right, I understand how the passing back to the onSuccess function works, I mean passing to the getUnreadEmails function. is it just getUnreadEmails(variable)?